# sorting multiple indexes array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

how to sort this kind of array? this will be sort by `array[x][1]`. can this be sorted using usort?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1247
            [1] => 3
            [2] => no
            [3] => no
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 224
            [1] => 1
            [2] => no
            [3] => no
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 226
            [1] => 2
            [2] => no
            [3] => no
        )

)
```

Comment: Could be more vague... How do you want to sort it? How do you want it displayed? Help us help you.

Comment: @Darren i would like to sort it by array[x][1]..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort), you simply need to compare against the 2<sup>*nd*</sup> element in the array (*as you required*).

```
usort($array, function($i, $v) {
    return $i[1] - $v[1];
});
```

<sup>***Note***: *The above `$array` is your array that you want to sort.*</sup>

Which will return it in the correct order (*`1`,`2` then `3`*).

[**Example/Demo**](https://www.tehplayground.com/rdz90sUtUiZQTTa1)

Comment: shouldn't that be `return $i[1] - $v[1];`?

Comment: `usort($array, function($i, $v) {
 return $i[1] - $v[1];
});
p($array);`

this one works for me! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ghost making 3rd coffee now *;-)*